# Ajax call always returning error 500 client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Im trying to post data back to a webmethod located in Default.aspx

jquery code:

```
data = "{'saveData':'testtestest'}"

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Default.aspx/SavePins",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d) {
                //    var obj = JSON.parse(response.d);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('#modalContentBox').html('Whoops! There was an error saving!').removeAttr('class').attr('class', 'alert alert-error');
            $('#myModal').modal();
        }
    });
```

Web Method:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool SavePins(string saveData)
{
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(string.Format("{0}{1}.shane", file_location, "pinsData"), saveData);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The issue is that the Ajax call always returns an error 500 client side. It does not actually post to the server. there is a `<form>` element with `runat="server"` in the page. I've added `<asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="True" runat="server"/>`

Comment: Well if you got a 500 back, that means the request made it to the server and the server rejected it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ScriptMethod to your web method because you needs to send the response as json.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]      
public bool SavePins(string saveData)
{
     try
      {
           File.WriteAllText(string.Format("{0}{1}.shane", file_location, "pinsData"),     saveData);
           return true;
      }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        return false;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Same thing. server responded with an error 500. didn't even hit the breakpoint inside the method

Comment: change your URL to full URL like
 url: "http://localhost:1111/Default.aspx/SavePins"